# First time using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

This is my first time using Tkinter and really trying to get use to using classes in Python. I wonder if I'm using self entirely too much, but here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MainFrame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.display()
    #display all the labels for the main frame
    def labels(self):
        #adding x-cord label
        x_cord_label = Label(self.top, text = 'X-Coordinate').grid(row=0,column = 0)
    #calls the visible features
    def display(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        self.labels()
        self.entries()
        self.buttons()
        #must remain at bottom or wont be displayed
        self.top.mainloop()


    #display all the entry boxes for the main frame
    def entries(self):
        x_cord_entry = Entry(self.top,bd=5).grid(row=0,column = 1)

    def buttons(self):
        x_cord_button = Button(self.top, text = 'Enter').grid(row=0,column = 2)
```

I am planning on main just having the mainframe being generated.

```
main.py
from mainFrame import MainFrame
def main():
    window = MainFrame()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Python has a set of rules for how documentation strings should look like. These strings are called `docstring`s in Python and the corresponding PEP is [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). You basically just move your comments from above the function name inside and make them strings:

```
def display(self):
    """Calls the visible features."""
    self.top = Tk()
    self.labels()
    self.entries()
    self.buttons()
    # must remain at bottom or wont be displayed
    self.top.mainloop()
```

Python also has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends adding a single space after the `#` in a comment, as well as using a single blank line between class methods (and two between class or normal function definitions). It also recommends using a space after a comma in an argument list, but no spaces surrounding `=` for keyword arguments.

Your method `display` could be moved completely to the `__init__`, but it is also fine as a separate method, in case you ever want to call it again to reset your application / display it again after changing some values. I would swap the `display` and `labels` methods, though, it makes for easier reading.

Regarding your doubt if you are overusing `self`, i think you are rather underusing it than overusing. I'm not exactly sure how `Tkinter` handles objects, but in Python in general, objects can and will be garbage-collected once they go outside of scope. So, after e.g. the method `labels` ran, the local variable `x_coord_label` will be removed and the associated object deleted (unless it is still being referenced from somewhere else, like the `Tk` main loop for example). So I would store these labels/buttons etc also as class members. This is handy if you ever want to modify them as well (changing the text label on a button is a quite regular feature...).

In general, [you should avoid using `from X import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided), because it clutters your global namespace and might lead to name conflicts. With `Tkinter`, many people use it anyway, mostly because one tends to use a lot of its functions, so selectively importing `from TKinter import Button, Label, ...` becomes too long and unreadable and always writing `Tkinter.Button` is also quite verbose. As a compromise you can use `import Tkinter as tk`, which is shorter and still has its own namespace.

**Final code:**

```
import Tkinter as tk


class MainFrame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.display()

    def display(self):
        """Calls the visible features."""
        self.top = tk.Tk()
        self.labels()
        self.entries()
        self.buttons()
        # must remain at bottom or wont be displayed
        self.top.mainloop()

    def labels(self):
        """Display all the labels for the main frame."""
        # adding x-cord label
        self.x_cord_label = tk.Label(
            self.top, text='X-Coordinate').grid(row=0, column=0)

    def entries(self):
        """Display all the entry boxes for the main frame."""
        self.x_cord_entry = tk.Entry(self.top, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=1)

    def buttons(self):
        self.x_cord_button = tk.Button(
            self.top, text='Enter').grid(row=0, column=2)
```

If you want to extend this further, you probably want to add more than one button. In this case, you will need to decide on a datastructure to hold your texts and buttons. So in the end it might look more like this:

```
class MainFrame(object):

    def __init__(self, button_texts):
        self.button_texts = button_texts
        self.top = tk.Tk()
        self.setup_rows()
        self.top.mainloop()

    def setup_rows(self):
        """
        Display all the rows with labels, entries and buttons
        for the main frame.
        """
        self.rows = []
        top = self.top
        for i, text in enumerate(self.button_texts):
            row = [tk.Label(top, text=text).grid(row=i, column=0),
                   tk.Entry(top, bd=5).grid(row=i, column=1),
                   tk.Button(top, text='Enter').grid(row=i, column=2)]
            self.rows.append(row)
```

Comment: In Python, it's also frowned upon to `import *` instead of the specific things to be used (e.g. `from math import sqrt`)

Comment: @ray Normally I would agree 100%, but with `Tkinter` this is quite often done anyway, because one uses quite a lot of its functions, so explicit importing from would be too long and always writing `Tkinter` would be too lengthy. I'll edit it to use `import Tkinter as tk`, as a compromise, though.

Comment: I understand. I think just noting this as an Tk-specific exception would be enough. I tried to use Tk once. After needing ~20 minutes to produce a main window with a single button I said "!@$ this !@#" and used PyQt instead.

Comment: I agree with @ray. To cut down on typing use `import tkinter as tk` and then use `tk.Button`, etc. It makes the code easier to maintain, easier to read, etc.

Comment: @Bryan Edited the answer to state that.